# Python `defaultdict`: Use default when setting, but not when getting

Tags: python, defaultdict

Is there any way I can make a `collections.defaultdict` return a default constructed object when I set it...

```
foo = defaultdict(list)
foo[3].append('dsafdasf')
```

... but not when I try to access it?

```
try:
   for word in foo[None]:
       print(word)
except KeyError:
    pass
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think that what you're looking for is something like this:

```
>>> foo = {}
>>> foo.setdefault(3, []).append('dsafdasf') # Appends to default value
>>> foo[None] # Raises a KeyError exception
```

That is, instead of using `collections.defaultdict`, you could use a regular dictionary and use `setdefault` method when you need to assign a default and item access when you need an exception to be raised for missing keys.

Answer (score 3):

No, because your example of "setting it" is actually an example of getting an unused slot.

Comment: I thought it might be possible since Python has the `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` functions.

Comment: @PaulManta it does have both those, but only `__getitem__` is being used here. `foo[3]` and `foo[None]` in your example are both just accessing the dict entry; only doing something like `foo[3] = ...` will call `__setitem__`.

Comment: It is possible if you are willing to resort to dirty hacks, such as inspecting the stack to determine the context. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61118676/nested-dictionary-that-acts-as-defaultdict-when-setting-items-but-not-when-getti/61143071#61143071